# Secure REST API with HTTP Basic authentication

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

I have created data_service using WSO2DSS version 3.0.1.
Service works perfectly, but I have not found solution how to secure REST API
using HTTP Basic authentication.

Which is best way to secure REST messages using basic authentication?
I would like to use users/roles from WSO2 "User management", but that is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement easiest way is to use fronted Wso2 ESB. Through esb you can secure your service.

Documentation on Securing REST APIs can be found at [1]  .

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ESB460/Securing+REST+APIs

Thank You,
Dharshana.